# How can I access a web site hosted in Openshift cluster from an IP issued by local dhcp server

Tags: docker, openshift, dhcp, openshift-origin

I have successfully deployed Openshift all in one cluster using the client 
tools provided in git hub.

./oc cluster up

And I also build a WordPress web site and a MySQL database for it. Both are working fine and now I want to access the web site via a local IP address in my network. So others can access my web site in the Openshift. I don't know how to do this. Tried as much as I can, cannot edit the master-config file as it is resides on docker container, when restarted it is gone, please help

thank you

Comment: I have a dhcp server in my lab. I want to assigns IP from this DHCP server to access the web site hosted in openshift

Comment: Are you aware of the ``--routing-suffix`` option to ``oc cluster up`` for defining your own hostname suffix for deployed applications?

Comment: no sir, i was not aware about that, what I want is to access the wordpress web site from outside. like normal. Let me check this and get back to you. thanks

Comment: No sir, I did not get what I want. there's no option to do that, I just want to access my WordPress website from my local network IP address. such as http://192.168.1.100:<port>

Comment: OpenShift relies on a FQDN and can't use an IP address to perform routing to the application in OpenShift. What you can do though is set a routing suffix ad ``192.168.1.100.nip.io``. You then may be able to access it as ``appname-projectname.192.168.1.100.nip.io``. The ``nip.io`` address are magic and allow you to refer to an IP using a FQDN.

Comment: ohh, got it. thx sir

Answer (score 0):

You can bring up the cluster using your IP address 
something like:

> oc cluster up --public-hostname=192.168.122.154

Check

> oc status

once the cluster is up and use the URL to access.